# UIView шестиугольная iOS

Tags: ios, view

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу сделать шестиугольную uiview?

Answer (score 1):

UIView всегда прямоугольные, однако слои, с помощью которых они реализованы, могут иметь маску - другой слой, определяющий, какая часть этого слоя отрисована, а какая - нет.

Поэтому рецепт такой: в designated initializer вашей вьюшки создаете [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/) вашей шестиугольной формы, а затем делаете из него маску

```
UIBezierPath *path = … // тут задаете форму шестиугольника как вам надо
CAShapeLayer *mask = CAShapeLayer.new;
mask.path = path
self.layer.mask = mask;
```

Углы шестиугольника - 120 градусов (2π/3 радиан). Например, если ваша вьюшка имеет ширину `2 * N` и высоту `sqrt(3.) * N`:

```
// получаем длину стороны шестиугольника
CGFloat n = 0.5 * self.bounds.size.width;

const CGFloat sin = 0.5 * sqrt(3.), cos = 0.5;
UIBezierPath *path = UIBezierPath.new;
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(cos * n, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake((2 - cos) * n, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(2 * n, sin * n)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake((2 - cos) * n, 2 * sin * n)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(cos * n, 2 * sin * n)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, sin * n)];
[path closePath];
```

Если вы хотите заполнить пространство сотами, вам понадобится также другой вариант шестиугольника, который вы можете получить вращением этого или аналогично с помощью школьной геометрии (что по идее должно дать бОльшую точность).

Comment: Спасибо! сейчас попробую

Comment: @AlexeySlivkin исправил, первый раз забыл умножить Y на синус угла

Comment: Получилось что-то не то))
https://yadi.sk/i/jw-3Xy1_h7z7e

Comment: А если n сделать меньше? Я сам не проверял, скорее всего где-то обсчитался :)